# how to pass composite object to view model

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm using mvvm light with wpf.

Currently i can pass string parameter to viewmodel's command like below:

```
<TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Name="textbox1"/>
<Button Command="{Binding ShowMessage}" Content="Click Me"
        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=textbox1, Path=Text}" />
```

My question is how to pass composite type like Person to a command of ViewModel?

Thanks

Comment: same way, pass the person in the command param in XAML, just change your command to be of type <Person>

Comment: @denismorozov how i populate an instance of Person in XAML from textboxes?

Answer (score 1):

```
<TextBox Height="23" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Name="textbox1" Tag="{Binding Person}"/>
<Button Command="{Binding ShowMessage}" Content="Click Me"
CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=textbox1, Path=Tag}" />
```

you can make use of Tag Property of TextBox but I think there is something wrong with your MVVM implementation,It is the ViewModel that holds the data for your view.  But here you sending it from View to VM . I mean Person should be automatically there in your VM instead of sending it from View.

Comment: @you misunderstood me, suppose i have a windows (view) for creating person (inserting), how should i pass person data to viewmodel?

Comment: r.zarei, you misunderstood @ethicallogics. :) Your VM should create the Person object in response to a Command sent from the Button. In other words, all your logic is in the VM - the View is just a trigger.